# In Visual Studio 2015 Self Signed SSL Cert SHA-1

Tags: ssl, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio 2015, just created a new MVC / Web Api project to experiment using https.  The sites I am currently using as a walkthrough (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-deploy-aspnet-mvc-app-membership-oauth-sql-database/) and (http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on) seem pretty straight forward.

I have accepted the self signed certificate VS 2015 IIS Express creates however I am getting Warnings in Chrome that it uses a deprecated signature algorithm based on SHA-1.  Other research suggests that chrome is phasing out support for SHA-1 certificates.

What do I need to do inside Visual Studio to upgrade the signature algorithm creating the Self Signed SSL Certs from SHA-1 to SHA-256 for any new certificates that get created in the future?

Answer (score 1):

there is a link here but i couln't do it myself. maybe it will work for you

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/br230260.aspx

1. In Solution Explorer, open the shortcut menu for the .appxmanifest
   file, choose Open With, and then choose App Manifest Designer.
2. In the App Manifest Designer, choose the Packaging tab, and then choose
   the Choose Certificate button.
3. In the Choose Certificate dialog box, expand the Configure Certificate list, and then choose one of the following options:

   - Pick from certificate store

     - Pick one of your Personal certificates from the certificate store in the operating system.
   - Select from file

     - Pick an existing certificate file from the file system.
   - Create test certificate

     - Create a certificate with a Publisher ID of your choice. You can also create a password.

**UPDATED (26.07.2018):** Actually  there is Let's Encrypt certificates you could use for free.

There one cmd option: [win-acme](https://github.com/PKISharp/win-acme)
and there is another with gui: [certifytheweb](https://certifytheweb.com/)